# Upgrade from restful_authentication to devise :confirmable not confirming old users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, restful-authentication, devise-confirmable

I have upgraded my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.2.2. I have replaced authentication from restful authentication to devise with guidance of steps given in devise wiki.

I have user model as

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable, :validatable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :encryptable,:encryptor => :restful_authentication_sha1,:authentication_keys => [:login]
```

When I tried to login with old user then I am unable to login because of confirmation token matching problem.I can login with new user after confirmation

BUT when I remove `:confirmable` from devise options. I can login with old user too.

I have added **pepper** and stretches

```
config.stretches = 10

config.pepper = "<KEY_FOR_SITE>"
```

Another thing is that when I try to login with unconfirmed user the notice will not be displayed just login page refreshes

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
config.stretches = 1
config.pepper = ''
```